# increase efficiency of sqoop export from hdfs

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, vertica, mapper

I am trying to **export data using sqoop** from files stored in hdfs to vertica. For around 10k's of data the files get loaded within a few minutes. But when I try to run crores of data, it is loading around .5% within 15 mins or so. I have tried to increase the ***number of mappers***, but they are not serving any purpose to improve efficienct. Even setting the ***chunk size*** to increase the number the mappers, does not increase the number.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the network bandwidth.

Comment: @Shilpa What is your cluster size i.e Number of nodes in cluster?

Comment: @Sachin Janani : Around 10 nodes. Here I am using the batch command. Maybe that can be the reason for such a slow performance.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Batch export try increasing the records per transaction and records per statement parameter using the following properties:

`sqoop.export.records.per.statement :`   property will aggregate multiple rows inside one single insert statement.

`sqoop.export.records.per.transaction:` how many insert statements will be issued per transaction

I hope these will surely solves the issue.

Comment: Ok I havent tried this yet.. will surely give a try! :)

Answer (score 0):

Most MPP/RDBMS have sqoop connectors to exploit the parallelism and increase efficiency in transfer of data between HDFS and MPP/RDBMS. However it seems the vertica has taken this approach: http://www.vertica.com/2012/07/05/teaching-the-elephant-new-tricks/
https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Hadoop-Connector

Answer (score 0):

Is this a "wide" dataset? It might be a sqoop bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2920 if number of columns is very high (in hundreds), sqoop starts choking (very high on cpu). When number of fields is small, it's usually other way around - when sqoop is bored and rdbms systems can't keep up.